# Absolute Convergence in Probability

Tags: measure-theory

$X_{1},X_{2},...$ are random variables, with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[\left | X_{n} \right |]<\infty$. My goal is to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}X_{n}$ converges absolutely with probability 1.

So, I have to prove that

$$\mathbb{P}(\left \{ \omega \in \Omega:lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left | X_{j} \right |=L, \ L<\infty \right \})=1$$

First, I define  $B_{n,k}=\left \{ \omega \in \Omega:\left | \sum_{j=1}^{n}\left | X_{j} \right |-L\leq \frac{1}{k} \right | \right \}$

And then I have to prove that the following has probability 1.

$$\mathbb{P}(\cap_{k=1}^{\infty}\cup_{m=1}^{\infty}\cap_{n=m}^{\infty}B_{n,k})=1$$

From decreasing monotonicity property we have that

$$=lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{P}(\cup_{m=1}^{\infty}\cap_{n=m}^{\infty}B_{n,k})$$

And then it seems that I can use the Borel-Cantelli Lemma , but how do I show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(B_{n,k})<\infty$, i.e. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(\left \{ \omega \in \Omega:\left | \sum_{j=1}^{n}\left | X_{j} \right |-L \right |\leq \frac{1}{k} \right \})<\infty$.

I could use Chebyshev inequality but $L$ is not the mean value of $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left | X_{j} \right |$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Fubini's theorem,
$$
\mathbb E\left[\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\vert X_n\vert\right]=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\mathbb E[\vert X_n\vert]<+\infty.
$$

Hence the random variable $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\vert X_n\vert$ is integrable and therefore almost surely finite, which means that with probability $1$, $\sum_{n\ge1}\vert X_n\vert$ is absolutely convergent.